# How to make scrollable Tabrow fill max width in landscape mode in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, landscape-portrait, android-scrollable-tabs

When changing screen orientation to landscape mode, the Scrollable Tabrow only occupies half of the screen, as in this image. I want to make it fill max width of the screen.

As of the following code, I've made the scrollable tabrow fill max width.

[image]

```
ScrollableTabRow(
        selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        edgePadding = 0.dp,
        divider = {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
        },
        indicator = { tabPositions ->
            SecondaryIndicator(
                modifier = Modifier.customTabIndicatorOffset(
                    currentTabPosition = tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage],
                    tabWidth = tabWidths[pagerState.currentPage]
                ),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
            )
        },


        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.mainAppBar)
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {
        tabData.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
            Tab(
                modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.mainAppBar),
                selected = pagerState.currentPage == index, onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                }
            },
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                            tabWidths[index] =
                                with(density) { textLayoutResult.size.width.toDp() }
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making it full width you have to use `TabRow` which is not scrollable and tabs are created with equal weight making it fill the width. However you have to be sure that in landscape all items will fit into `TabRow`.

I updated your code:

- for portrait `ScrollableTabRow` is used where tabs occupying just that space they need and row is scrollable
- for landscape `TabRow` is used where items fills maximum width but they are not scrollable. It's almost the same, only difference is that `TabRow`does not have `edgePadding` property.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomTabsRow() {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val tabData = remember {
        listOf("Events", "Details", "Lineups", "Stats", "Endings")
    }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState {
        tabData.size
    }

    if (configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            divider = {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
            },
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                SecondaryIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.customTabIndicatorOffset(
                        currentTabPosition = tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage],
                        tabWidth = tabWidths[pagerState.currentPage]
                    ),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                )
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.mainAppBar)
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            tabData.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.mainAppBar),
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index, onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = title,
                            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                                tabWidths[index] =
                                    with(density) { textLayoutResult.size.width.toDp() }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        ScrollableTabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
            edgePadding = 0.dp,
            divider = {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
            },
            indicator = { tabPositions ->
                SecondaryIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier.customTabIndicatorOffset(
                        currentTabPosition = tabPositions[pagerState.currentPage],
                        tabWidth = tabWidths[pagerState.currentPage]
                    ),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                )
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.mainAppBar)
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            tabData.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                    modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.mainAppBar),
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index, onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = title,
                            onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
                                tabWidths[index] =
                                    with(density) { textLayoutResult.size.width.toDp() }
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```